# Формы слова "Аде'я"

Tags: падежи, множественное-число, ударение

В словаре Даля есть слово "Аде'я" - "Ад". Ударение указано на "я".
Меня поглощает вопрос - какая будет форма слова для родительного падежа множественного числа?

Ад'ей?

Можно ли по этому слову определить ударение единственного числа именительного падежа?

Ад'ея?

Аде'я?

Если взять "идея", то мн.ч. р.п. будет

Идей

Но начальная форма с ударением на "е". В таком случае выходит, что "ад'ея" и "аде'я" имеют общую форму в мн. ч. р.п. - "ад'ей". Так?

Просто душа терзалась вопросом, есть ли четкое разграничение инфинитива, если имеется только "ад'ей"?

Comment: Лучше подумайте над родительным множественного слов *мзда* и *тля*. ;)

Comment: Вопрос - не вопрос.  Тля - тлей, подумал я, что так и оказалось - https://kak-pishetsya.com/Тля. С "мзда" было сложнее. Пришло нп ум лишь "мзд", что чудаковато. Этот сайт вариант не даёт. Однако даёт викисловарь - https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/мзда. Вышло опять-таки так же - мзд. Невероятно. Слово без гласных да еще и во множественном. Буду им теперь щеголять при случае.

Comment: МЗДА — МЗДА, мзды, мн. нет, жен. Награда, плата, вознаграждение (книжн. устар.; теперь шутл.). Получить мзду. «Истинная благость без всякой мзды добро творит.» Крылов. || Взятка, (разг. ирон.). За соответствующую мзду. Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н.… …   Толковый словарь Ушакова

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any reason not to decline it according to Zaliznyak's paradigm 6b, same as *швея́ / шве́й, ворожея́ / вороже́й, колея́ / коле́й*  etc.

This would give *адея́ / аде́й*

Our very own Sergey Slepov maintains an online edition of Zaliznyak's dictionary, which provides a [detailed algorithm](https://gramdict.ru/declension/symbols#declension) on finding the declension paradigm for practically any Russian word.

Answer (score 1):

Можно было бы адресовать вас к слову «колея», которое , как и «адея» (ад) является существительным женского рода с ударением на последний гласный, но , к сожалению, вопрос не имеет смысла, поскольку у некоторых существительных, в том числе и «ад», «рай» **нет множественного числа**, см.словари **Ушакова**, Орфоэпический словарь русского языка Аванесова.
При чём тут инфинитив, честно говоря, вообще непонятно.

Слово "мзда" тоже **не имеет множественного числа**, см. те же словари.